# How to get Json string from webpage by Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json

I have post value to text field and it return JSON string, how to post value/receive JSON string.

here is my code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.donxebuyt.com/"]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:txtFrom.text forKey:@"id_locA"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);
}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 9):

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error=nil;
NSDictionary *response=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error]; 
NSString* sth=[response objectForKey: @"some_your_key"];
```

`sth` is a new variable and post it as you POST it above

Answer (score 1):

iOS has a built in json serializing framework(just include the JSON.framework in your project) or there are some open source frameworks such as JSONKit: https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit